# Need a Query for displaying BOOLEAN TRUE values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, date,
CASE WHEN 
ITEM_DESC LIKE '%low_price%' OR 
ITEM_DESC LIKE '%medium%' OR 
ITEM_DESC LIKE '%high%' OR
ITEM_DESC LIKE '%cheap%'
THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS PRICE_IND      
FROM table_1 A
JOIN table_2 C
ON A.price_ind_id = C.price_ind_id
JOIN table_3 U
ON C.price_ind_id=U.price_ind_id
WHERE 
AND id='129342'
GROUP BY id,date,PRICE_IND;
```

When I run the above query, I'm getting 2 rows. I'm getting one value as 'TRUE' and the other value as 'FALSE'.

```
Row     ID               DATE        PRICE_IND
1     129342            2021-10-02    TRUE
2     129342            2021-10-02    FALSE
```

If there is at least one 'TRUE' value, I need to display the result is 'TRUE'. The expected result should be displayed as mentioned below:

```
   Row     ID               DATE        PRICE_IND    EXPECTED_RESULT 
    1     129342            2021-10-02    TRUE          TRUE
```

Guide me on this please.

Comment: Add the case statement to the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be done with [BOOLOR_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/boolor_agg.html):

> Returns the logical (boolean) OR value of all non-NULL boolean records in a group.
>
> BOOLOR_AGG returns ‘true’ if at least one record in the group evaluates to ‘true’.

```
SELECT  id, date,
BOOLOR_AGG(ITEM_DESC LIKE ANY ('%low_price%','%medium%', '%high%','%cheap%'))
           AS PRICE_IND      
FROM table_1 A
JOIN table_2 C
  ON A.price_ind_id = C.price_ind_id
JOIN table_3 U
  ON C.price_ind_id=U.price_ind_id
WHERE id='129342'
GROUP BY id,date;
```